# Manually update web worker messages

Tags: javascript, dom-events, web-worker

I have a web worker in which I'm trying to run as little asynchronous code as possible.

I would like to have a while loop in my web worker while still allowing messages to be processed. Is there a way to manually update the event system in the browser? Or at least update the web worker's messages?

There appears to be something like this in Node.js (`process._tickDomainCallback()`) but so far I haven't found anything for web.

Using a `setTimeout` is not an option. I would like either a solution or a definitive answer that this is simply not possible.

```
// worker.js

self.onmessage = function(e) {
   console.log("Receive Message");
};

while (true) {
  UpdateMessages(); // Receive and handle incoming messages

  // Do other stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your context is here ... I had an issue where the browser side Web Audio API event loop was getting interrupted at inopportune moments by WebSocket traffic coming in from my nodejs server so I added a WebWorker middle layer to free up the browser event loop from ever getting interruptions

The WebWorker handled all network traffic then populated a circular queue with data ... when the browser event loop deemed itself available it plucked data from this shared queue (using Transferable Object buffer) and so was never interrupted since it was the one initiating calls to the WebWorker

I feel your pain however this approach kept the event loop happy ... since a WebWorker is effectively on its own thread and from the browser side is doing  async work, there is no need to minimize async code

Comment: My case is as simple as it gets. I want users to run their own JavaScript code but would still like to allow for complete synchronous programs. But I still need to communicate with this web worker. Mainly since I need to know when the program is done executing. Instead I now overwrote the setTimeout in order to pull this off. Still wondering if there's an actual solution but for now this'll do.